# Getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for every jar file

Tags: java, android, jar

I have recently reinstalled my computer, installed latest version of Android SDK and Eclipse.
And now every project that I have, I'm getting a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" for every jar file included in every project.

I am a Java beginner, I have spend the last week on forums, but cannot get to fix it.

Could someone please help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were probably using an out-of-date version of ADT prior to reformatting. Post ADT 17, libraries either need to be copied to the `libs` folder of your project, or they need to be marked as exported on the build path. Otherwise, the libraries will not be packaged with the APK binary, thus you will get `NoClassDefFoundError` when using those libraries.

Comment: Thank you! My jar files where in a "lib" folder, not a "libs" folder!!