# if i change extends Activity to OrmLiteBaseActivity<Helper> i get an java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, android-activity, noclassdeffounderror, ormlite

i begin to develop for android and use the "ormlite" ORM-mapper (SQLite).
The Mapper has a OrmLiteBaseActivity Class, this extends from Activity. If i change "MainActivity extends Activity" to "MainActivity extends OrmLiteBaseActivity" the code compiled without errors. On the first access (MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()) to this class, i get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

I dont understand what is the problem.

Thank you, for helping.

Comment: Where do you get the OrmLiteBaseActivity from?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure what the problem is but I suspect that your [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) jars are *not* in the `libs` subdirectory under your Android project.  This was changed in recent versions of the Google Eclipse plugin.

See this question: [Getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for every jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669771/getting-a-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-for-every-jar-file)

Comment: Nice, this was the problem. Thank you.